# Dataframe groupby to count frequency and write to Excel

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table

A data-frame that I want to do some Excel pivot-table alike summary, like the screenshot below.

[image]

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'People' : ["David","Kate","Kate","Kate","David","David","Kate","David","Kate"],
'Year': ["2016","2016","2016","2017","2017","2017","2016","2017","2016"],
'Project' : ["TN","DM","TN","DM","DJ","DM","DM","DM","TN"]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df_1 = df.groupby(['People', 'Year', 'Project'])["Project"].count()
```

df_1 output as below:

[image]

Then I want to export all with no blank cells to Excel spreadsheet.

```
df_1.reset_index().to_excel('file.xlsx', index=False)
```

But it gives me error:

```
ValueError: cannot insert Project, already exists
```

I tried below also doesn't work:

```
df_1.reset_index().to_excel('file.xlsx', index=False)
```

What's the right way to write it? Thank you.

Comment: you need  each index not to by grouped and printed for each line before save? After `df_1.to_excel('file.xlsx')` data is saved with ok format

Comment: @Zaraki Kenpachi, thanks for the comment. df_1.to_excel('file.xlsx') writes to file with some empty cells, that I don't want. So added the ".reset_index()".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
df_1 = df.groupby(['People', 'Year', 'Project'])["Project"].count().reset_index(name="count")
df_1.to_excel('file.xlsx')
```